# Making a augmented matrix in matlab, and reduced row echelon form

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to combine matrix A and matrix b to make an augmented matrix [A|b], where b is the solution to matrix A and such that a vertical bar is shown in the output on matlab?If so, is it possible to rref([A|b]) so that the augmented matrix is displayed in reduced row echelon form?

```
    >> A =[-1 1 1; 3 -1 0; 2 -4 -5];
      A =

      -1     1     1
       3    -1     0
       2    -4    -5

    >> b = [0;0;0];
      b =

       0
       0
       0
```

When I tried entering [A|b], it gives me

```
Error using  | 
Inputs must have the same size.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Augment matrices in Matlab using commas to put to the right and semi-colons to put below (similar to how you define matrices to begin with).

```
combined = [A,b]; % b is to the right of A
```